# Is it okay to pour concrete over geotextile fabric?

Tags: concrete, landscaping

I am installing artificial turf in my backyard. I would like to divide it with a path filled with decorative rocks.

The whole area was excavated 4" deep and I covered it with geotextile fabric liner to keep weeds from growing. The area with grass is filled with base rocks and topped with a bit of sand. The path is completely filled with white rocks. I need an edge to divide the base rocks from the decorative rocks.

I was thinking of using 2" thick patio paver and pour cement under it. **Is it okay to just pour it over the geotextile fabric?**

I saw on YouTube people pouring dry sand cement and just resting the pavers on top. When everything is leveled and aligned, they just spray mist. Seem easy. No digging. This is not structural. Just for decorative purposes and to keep the 2 types of rocks from mixing up.

This is how I would build up my edge/border
[image: How I would install my edge]

An example of a lawn with a path with rocks. Mine will be fake grass with a curved border.
[image: An example of lawn with a path with rocks. Mine will be fake grass with a curved border]

Brick paver I would use for the edge
[image: Brick paver I would use for the edge]

Comment: Is the brick part of the design you want?  If not why not use actual edging?  Steel, Vinyl, wood, right down to the fabric.  Like in the photo, I think that's wood.

Comment: @jay613 i ruled out wood because my border is curved and it will rot over time.  I also rule out steel because of rusting.  I guess I could go with Vinyl but having a larger border makes it look more attractive.